# Get records of the last X days

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

The code below returns me all data that are present in *CollectionA* but NOT in *CollectionB*. (Using the `mainID` as reference).

```js
  return this.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'CollectionB',
        localField: 'mainId',
        foreignField: 'mainId',
        as: 'validd',
      },
    },
    {
      $match: {
        'validd.mainId': { $exists: false },
      },
    },
  ]);
```

But now I need to add another **filter**.  I also need to get data where the field `createdAt` is **greater than 90 days.**
in other words: Records that have more than 90 days of life.

Tried using `$gte` and `$lte` inside `$match`  but didn't work.

```js
{
  $match: {
    'validd.createdAt': { $gte: moment.utc().add(-90, "days") },
  },
},
```

This returns nothing.

My database:

```json
{
  _id: 227dd33c5c51c79f63743da3
  mainId: 5c306562-9c87-48dd-93ca-4a118be50490
  createdAt: 2022-05-07T02:28:12.537+00:00
},
{
  _id: f3ddd33c5c51c79f63743da3
  mainId: 5c306562-9c87-48dd-93ca-4a118be50490
  createdAt: 2022-05-10T02:28:12.537+00:00
},
{
  _id: 227dd33c5c51c79f63743da3
  mainId: 5c306562-9c87-48dd-93ca-4a118be50490
  createdAt: 2022-01-01T02:28:12.537+00:00
}
```

we can ignore all the data, just need to focus oon `createdAt`.
I want to keep the **$lookup** logic but also add the filter to return only rows where `createdAt` is greater than 90 days (considering the current day / Today).

So with this logic, only the **last** record should be returned, because all the rest of the rows were created in **less than 90 days ago**

---

**EDIT**

To clarify. I need to return data if:

1. row of collectionA does NOT exists in collectionB
2. row of collectonA exists in collectionB **BUT** `createdAt` is greater than X days.

Tried this based on the answer of @ray

```
  return this.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'CollectionB',
        localField: 'mainId',
        foreignField: 'mainId',
        as: 'validd',
      },
    },
    {
      $match: {
        $expr: {
          $or: [
            {
              $eq: ["$validd", []]
            },
            {
              $and: [
                {
                  $lt: [ "validd.createdAt", moment.utc().add(-interval, "days").format('YYYY-MM-DD') ]
                },
                {
                  $ne: ["validd", null]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
    },
  ]);
```

Comment: would be helpful if we can have some sample data and expected output

Comment: @ray hi! Added some more explanation and example of expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `$or` in the `$expr` in `$match`

```js
db.CollectionA.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "CollectionB",
      "localField": "mainId",
      "foreignField": "mainId",
      "as": "validd"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        $or: [
          {
            $eq: [
              "$validd",
              []
            ]
          },
          {
            $and: [
              {
                $ne: [
                  "$validd",
                  []
                ]
              },
              {
                $lt: [
                  "$createdAt",
                  {
                    "$dateSubtract": {
                      "startDate": "$$NOW",
                      "unit": "day",
                      "amount": 90
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FtkcKfABn6H) for your reference.

---

For version prior to MongoDB v5.0, you can `$subtract` `$$NOW` for 90 days * 24 hours * 60 min * 60 sec * 1000 ms = 7776000000 and compare to the subtraction result as an alternative.

```js
db.CollectionA.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "CollectionB",
      "localField": "mainId",
      "foreignField": "mainId",
      "as": "validd"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        $or: [
          {
            $eq: [
              "$validd",
              []
            ]
          },
          {
            $and: [
              {
                $ne: [
                  "$validd",
                  []
                ]
              },
              {
                $lt: [
                  "$createdAt",
                  {
                    "$subtract": [
                      "$$NOW",
                      7776000000
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mMXxweqJh41) for your reference.

Comment: Thank you! I'm receiving a `InvalidPipelineOperator`, but I believe I just need to fix something with node and mongoose.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro what is your mongodb version? The `$dateSubtract` function may not be available in older version. I have added another alternative for version before MongoDB v5.0

Comment: Thank you @ray. I added a little bit more context, if you have the tim to take a look.